# How can I use a library from GitHub in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, github

I am completely new to dealing with GitHub libraries.

I have a project in my android studio and I need to use this library **https://github.com/kedzie/DraggableDrawers** from git to help me implement a draggable drawer in my project . How can I do that step by step please?

Comment: There are an unbelievable amount of tutorials on how to do this on the web.

Comment: The coordinates of the library in question are `com.github.kedzie.draggabledrawers:library:1.0.0`. Use that in the dependencies section of your build.gradle.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkRotteveel . It worked but do you know how can I get the coordinates for future usage .. I mean how can I get what you got for this library?

Comment: The coordinates are specified in the README.md of that project, but then in Maven style (though incorrectly, it has switched the values for groupId and artifactId). Most projects will document their coordinates explicitly in some form, and a lot of projects will link to Maven Search or equivalent (e.g. for this project, [this link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.kedzie.draggabledrawers/library/1.0.0/apklib)), which will list it for various build tools, including Gradle.